# How to properly iterate through this two dimensional javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I have a sheet like this:

[image]

And I have this function:

```
    function getRangeAsArrays(sheet) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var array = [];  
  for (var r=0; r<sheet.getLastColumn(); r++) {
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    array.push(row);
       }
    }
  return array;
}
```

Which I use to build a `listbox`this way:

```
   var recipientArray = getRangeAsArrays(activeSheet);
  var item3Panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  item3Panel.add(app.createLabel("recipient"));
  var listBox = app.createListBox().setName('item3');  
  for(var i = 0; i < (recipientArray.length); i++){
  Logger.log("recipientArray[i][2] = " + recipientArray[i][3]);
  Logger.log(" i = " + i);
      listBox.addItem(recipientArray[i][4]);
    }
  item3Panel.add(listBox);
```

But when I iterate over the array length (4 rows), I got this (unexpected to me) result and the logs shows `i` variable goes until `14`:

[image]

Since `recipientArray.length` should give me the first dimension of the 2 dimensional array and `recipientArray[i].length` the second dimension, and since I want the first dimension (number of rows) row to fix that? What is going wrong here?

Comment: not sure I understand exactly what you need... what data should be in each listItem ?

Comment: Hi, @Sergeinsas, each row is been repeated 3 times in the listbox. I need each row to generate one (and only one) item list for that row. Thanks!

Comment: @Sergeinsas, look what is on my table: http://pho.to/551NP =)) I'll start reading it this weekend

Comment: :-)  excellent!!!  Thank you!  If ever you find something unclear you know where to find me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I'm still unsure that I understood what you need (I guess I'm a bit tired or I become stupid... go figure...:), I wonder why you try using separate functions since the value returned by `range.getValues()` is already an array... A 2D array but still an array.

If you want to create one listBox per row and add the following cells as items then a double loop like this will do the job. (tell me if I'm completely off the subject, thx).

I wrote an example code with the main structure and comments to explain where things go.

```
function test() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(data)
  var array = [];  // this is useless
  for (var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {

    // create listBox widget here
    //var listBox = app.createListBox().setName('listBox'+r);   
    for (i in data[0]) {
      var cell = data[r][i];

      //add items to listBox here
      // listBox.addItem(cell);
      array.push(cell);// this is useless
    }
  }
  Logger.log(array);//useless
  return array;//useless
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sergeinsas!! You are not tired or stupid, I didn't realize that the `range` already give me a 2 dimensional array! So, I was puting more dimensions on it! Thanks A LOT! I give a look on your book and I like books with a lot of code to read. I've alread rate it on Amazon! Thanks for writing this book. I will fill a lot of gaps in my GAS knowledge!